# Using python multiprocess outside the main script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming) of python's multiprocess the spawning of process needs to be inside of the `if __name__ == '__main__':` clause to prevent spawning infinite processes.

My question, is it possible to use multiprocess inside of an import?

Something along those lines of this:
let's say I have this py which is the main executed file:

```
import foo

def main():
    foo.run_multiprocess()

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

and the foo.py file which is imported:

```
def run_multiprocess(number_to_check):
    if number_to_check == 5:
        print(number_to_check)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_to_check = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
    pool = Pool(processes=4)             
    pool.map(process_image, list_to_check)
```

Obviusly this won't work because the code inside the if statment in foo.py won't run. Is there a way to make it work though?

Answer (score 5):

Multiprocessing doesn't have to run within the `__main__` block, `__main__` block is only used if the file is ran via `python filename.py`.

So if you did:

`m1.py`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool    
def f(x):
    return x^2

def f2():
    p = Pool(5)
    p.map(f, [1,2,3,4,5])
```

`m2.py`:

```
from m1 import f2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f2() # this would run multiprocessing code
```

and then call `python m2.py`, your code would run correctly, with mp.

Comment: As far as I understand, when you do 'from m1 import f2' it will create a new process. On windows it will *copy all* the fields of the original process to the new process. While creating the new process it will also execute the line 'from m1 import f2' again and because it's not in a '__main__' clause it will create *a new process* again and again and again

Comment: `this is not required, but a good practice` wrong. This _is_ required. You _have_ to call `f2` inside either a function or an `if`-clause that isn't executed on the module level. If you actauly tried the code you posted as an answer, you could've even noticed yourself.

Comment: @Nearoo Yes, I meant `if __name__ == "__main__":` as there's no `def __main__`

Comment: yes, but more importantly, you _do need this line_.